# I can't convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, data-analysis

I downloaded a database related to the stock market, where the values are expressed in the varchar(50) data type. I wanted to convert them to money so that I could perform actions on them.

Unfortunately, I can't do this either through the following command, or through the design option.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100
ALTER COLUMN High money;
```

What can I do?

[Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WccfS.png)

Comment: You'll need to fix the data. Run this to see a sample of problem values: `SELECT TOP 10 High FROM dbo.MASDAQ100 WHERE ISNUMERIC(High) = 0;`

Comment: @DanGuzman
I know that I have to fix the data but I don't know how can I do this:
PS. I have executed your command and have had no results.

Comment: Rather than `WHERE ISNUMERIC(High) = 0` I'd recommend `WHERE TRY_CAST(High AS money) IS NULL` instead. The `ISNUMERIC()` function is too accepting of values that can't actually be converted to `money`, such as `'1e1'`.

Comment: Use the `TRY_CAST` function @AlwaysLearning suggested. To fix it, you'll need to modify the problem values with an `UPDATE` statement to conform to implicit conversion rules.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I used the command: SELECT TOP 10 High FROM dbo.NASDAQ100 
WHERE TRY_CAST(High AS money) IS NULL. I still have any result.

Comment: @DanGuzman Could you tell me how to use all command also with update? Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` _should_ find the data that needs to be fixed but apprently it isn't. What does this do: `select cast([High] as MONEY) FROM dbo.NASDAQ100` You could also try inspecting visually by using something like this: `SELECT TOP 100 [High] FROM dbo.NASDAQ100 ORDER BY [High]` and `SELECT TOP 100 [High] FROM dbo.NASDAQ100 ORDER BY [High] DESC`

Comment: Are you saying no rows are returned with `TRY_CAST(High AS money) IS NULL`?

Comment: You might like to give examples and tell us how 'money' is where you are for example do you have comma thousand separators stored, have you stored currency code, how many decimal places do you have is the decimal a full stop or a comma..(etc)

Answer (score 0):

About all you can do here is identify which values aren't going to convert to a MONEY data type, then make whatever adjustments you need to do to fix them.

As an example, I'll create a table with some dummy data, setting the [low] and [high] column data types to VARCHAR(50):

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100
(
    [stock_code] CHAR(3)     NULL
    , [low]      VARCHAR(50) NULL
    , [high]     VARCHAR(50) NULL
) ;
GO
INSERT
    INTO    dbo.NASDAQ100 ( [stock_code], [low], [high] )
    VALUES  (   'ABB'  , '101.3348'   , '103.2577' )
            , ( 'FRG'  , '4.5098'     , '4.5663' )
            , ( 'PLA'  , '40.0001'    , '4O.2121' )
            , ( 'RDG'  , 'USD8.7890'  , 'USD11.2345' )
            , ( 'ZZT'  , '2.8q87'     , '5.6996' ) ;
GO
```

A simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.NASDAQ100` query returns these results:

```
stock_code | low       | high
------------------------------------
ABB        | 101.3348  | 103.2577
FRG        | 4.5098    | 4.5663
PLA        | 40.0001   | 4O.2121
RDG        | USD8.7890 | USD11.2345
ZZT        | 2.8q87    | 5.6996
```

As you can see, the data's pretty dirty.

If I try to change the [low] and [high] column data types to MONEY now:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100 ALTER COLUMN [low] MONEY ;
ALTER TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100 ALTER COLUMN [high] MONEY ;
```

I get a `Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax` error.

As mentioned, the only real way to fix this is to identify which values need to be corrected, then manually correct them yourself.

The following query -- which utilises the TRY_CAST built-in function -- should identify which values won't successfully convert to a MONEY data type:

```sql
WITH cte_Nasdaq100 AS
(
    SELECT      [stock_code]
                , [low] AS [low_original_value]
                , TRY_CAST ( [low] AS MONEY ) AS [low_as_money]
                , [high] AS [high_original_value]
                , TRY_CAST ( [high] AS MONEY ) AS [high_as_money]
    FROM        dbo.NASDAQ100
)
SELECT      [stock_code]
            , CASE
                WHEN    [low_as_money] IS NULL
                    THEN    [low_original_value]
                ELSE        '-'
                END AS [low_values_to_be_fixed]
            , CASE
                WHEN    [high_as_money] IS NULL
                    THEN    [high_original_value]
                ELSE        '-'
                END AS [high_values_to_be_fixed]
FROM        cte_Nasdaq100
WHERE       [high_as_money] IS NULL
    OR      [low_as_money] IS NULL ;
GO
```

Running this query over my sample data, I get the following results:

```
stock_code | low_values_to_be_fixed | high_values_to_be_fixed
-------------------------------------------------------------
PLA        | -                      | 4O.2121
RDG        | USD8.7890              | USD11.2345
ZZT        | 2.8q87                 | -
```

Now, although the dirty values are identified, there's no way to determine what they should be. This is were you need to do some leg work and look them up.

Once you've got the correct values, run some UPDATE statements to make the corrections:

```sql
UPDATE      dbo.NASDAQ100
    SET     [high] = '40.2121'
    WHERE   [stock_code] = 'PLA' ;

UPDATE      dbo.NASDAQ100
    SET     [low] = '8.7890'
            , [high] = '11.2345'
    WHERE   [stock_code] = 'RDG' ;

UPDATE      dbo.NASDAQ100
    SET     [low] = '2.8987'
    WHERE   [stock_code] = 'ZZT' ;
GO
```

Now a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.NASDAQ100` query returns clean data:

```
stock_code | low      | high
--------------------------------
ABB        | 101.3348 | 103.2577
FRG        | 4.5098   | 4.5663
PLA        | 40.0001  | 40.2121
RDG        | 8.7890   | 11.2345
ZZT        | 2.8987   | 5.6996
```

And if I run the query to identify the dirty data again (i.e. `WITH cte_Nasdaq100 AS...`), it returns no results.

I can now change the data types on the [low] and [high] columns to MONEY without SQL Server spitting the dummy:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100 ALTER COLUMN [low] MONEY ;
ALTER TABLE dbo.NASDAQ100 ALTER COLUMN [high] MONEY ;
```

To test, I run a query with a computation in the results:

```sql
SELECT      [stock_code]
            , [low]
            , [high]
            , [high] - [low] AS [difference]
FROM        dbo.NASDAQ100 ;
GO
```

And here's the results:

```
stock_code | low      | high     | difference
---------------------------------------------
ABB        | 101.3348 | 103.2577 | 1.9229
FRG        | 4.5098   | 4.5663   | 0.0565
PLA        | 40.0001  | 40.2121  | 0.212
RDG        | 8.7890   | 11.2345  | 2.4455
ZZT        | 2.8987   | 5.6996   | 2.8009
```

Hope this helps.